# Laravel 5 query to sync manytomany data with extra column, to database

Tags: laravel

I have on my database these 3 tables:

users   (model User)

accounts (model Account)

user_accounts (relationship table many to many) (id, user_id, account_id, **role_id**)

The problem is in the user_accounts I have an additional column `role_id` the meaning is to invite many users with different access levels.

maybe using `$user->accounts()->sync($account, false);`

how to save the data in this table maybe using

Comment: Welcome to SO @broadcast. What have you already tried? Provide code please.

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships), you can do it as follows:

```
$user->accounts()->sync([$accountId => ['role_id' => $roleId]], false);
```